# How do I filter an rss feed using a regular expression on its contents?

Tags: .net, windows, rss, outlook

How do I filter an rss feed?

- I'm using windows
- The RSS feed is on an internal network (so I can't use external websites).
- The RSS reader I'd like to use is Outlook (again because of the internal network).
- I'm open to hearing about .net solutions.

Comment: What kind of filtering are you trying to do? Is the use of a regular expression a requirement? What does Outlook have anything to do with this? You want an Outlook add-in or something?

Comment: The filtering I'm trying to do: looking inside contents for filenames that end with .sql or contain Database so: the regular expression would be something like: /\.sql\b|Database/

Comment: I mention Outlook, because I wonder if I'm overlooking a feature they provide where you can filter contents for given feeds (although poking around I don't see any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm building an program in C#. Something like this:

```
string originalFeedUrl = args[ 0 ];
string regex = args[ 1 ];
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load( originalFeedUrl );

XmlNodeList descriptions = doc.SelectNodes( @"//item/description" );
foreach( XmlNode description in descriptions ) {
    if( !Regex.IsMatch( description.InnerText, regex ) )
        description.ParentNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(description.ParentNode );
}

Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
```